# Loading a twig partial with jQuery within symfony 5

Tags: jquery, symfony

I have code that is like this:

```
{% if cards|length > 0 %}
     <div id="card-wallet-insert">
          {% include 'account/include_wallet.html.twig' with cards %}
     </div>
{% endif %}
```

The idea here is that I have a partial that outputs data. Once the user performs an action, I want to reload this partial so that I don't have to manually update the data with every single possibility via jquery.

So if I want to load this partial in jQuery (for instance like `$(this).load('account/include_wallet.html.twig');` how do I do that with jQuery within Symfony's structure? Also with variables too if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reload this partial you can create a custom function in your Controller for example:

```
/**
 * @Route(..., name="your_route")
 */
public function partialIncludeWallet(...) {
    ...
    return $this->render('account/include_wallet.html.twig' ...);
}
```

And make an Ajax request (or fetch) with the route to request the rendering (made using the Controller)

Comment: Im wondering if there's a way to deny access to that route but only through ajax.

Comment: Why do you want to deny access to this route? You can put this route behind your firewall but only server side, do you want to secure it on client side?